# Python find string in URL after specific string

Tags: python, regex, string, text-parsing

I have URLs like this:

```
https://storage.cloud.google.com/test_bucket/first_test_user/0.jpg
```

With Python I need to find the bucket and blob value from it, so that I can assign the variables:

```
bucket = 'test_bucket'
blob = 'first_test_user/0'
```

I think I need regex for this but I could not manage to find the values within the string. It should be like:

```
bucket = find(substring between 3rd and 4th "/")
blob = find(substring between 4th "/" and ".jpg")
```

Would reaaaally appreciate your help since regex is really confusing for me, as a beginner..

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

txt = 'https://storage.cloud.google.com/test_bucket/first_test_user/0.jpg'
bucket, blob = re.findall(r"//[^/]+.([^/]+).([^/]+)/", txt)[0]
print(bucket, blob, sep='\n')
```

or, without re:

```
txt = 'https://storage.cloud.google.com/test_bucket/first_test_user/0.jpg'
s = txt.split('/')
bucket, blob = s[3], s[4]
print(bucket, blob, sep='\n')
```

Prints:

```
test_bucket
first_test_user
```

Comment: Thank you so much!